# How to exit menu in mutt when for instance searching

Tags: mutt

I have accidentally pressed, say, `n` in mutt which puts me into search at the bottom of the screen `Search for:`. How do I exit from this if I don't want to search? I have tried `esc` and `ctrl-c`, but the first doesn't work and the second asks me whether I want to quit mutt, which I don't...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-G</kbd> will exit from all mutt prompts.

This is the standard quit keybinding in Emacs, so its probably inherited from there. Also works in bash.